# Hive Query C# console application. System.Aggregate Exception

Tags: c#, linq, hive, azure-hdinsight

While executing Hive Query using C# console application. I get System.Aggregate Exception Inner Exception. Response status code does not indicate success: 500 (Server Error)

I have used the following sample code given by MSDN

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn749872.aspx

Kindly let me know how to resolve the issue

Answer (score 0):

HTTP code 500 means that this is an error on your server. In plain words, the server threw an exception when trying to process this POST request.

Answer (score 0):

firstly you can expand all exceptios like that;

```
private static Exception LogException(Exception ex)
{
    if (ex is AggregateException)
    {
        foreach (Exception item in (ex as AggregateException).InnerExceptions)
        {
            Logger.Log(GetException(item));
        }
    }
}

private static Exception GetException(Exception ex)
{
    while (ex.InnerException != null)
    {
        ex = ex.InnerException;
    }

    return ex;
}
```